# Multiline listbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox

The title kind of says it all, I want items in a listbox to be able to fill several lines. I haven't been able to find anything that can do this for asp.net. Yes, I know listbox wasn't made for multilines..

Or is there a better tool for this? The reason why I would like it to be a listbox is because I am using Jscript, and I couldn't find any solution on how to add items to a Listview through Javascript.

Comment: Hehe my bad :) What do you mean by "add items to a Listview through Javascript"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listbox items aren't meant to contain several lines. Instead I constructed a table and styled it so it looked lkie one.